# Ricci Curvature and Sectional Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature

If we define the Ricci curvature for an orthonormal frame, we can simplify the sectional curvature formula to get:

$$Ric(v, v) = \sum R(e_i, v)v \cdot e_i$$

However, I obtain a different formula to the one that is ordinarily presented. Supposing we replace $v$ for its components and use the linearity of the Riemann curvature tensor, we can write:

$$Ric(v, v) = \sum R(e_i, v^je_j)v^ke_k \cdot e_i$$
$$Ric(v, v) = \sum v^j v^k R(e_i, e_j)e_k \cdot e_i$$
$$Ric(v, v) = \sum v^j v^k R^m_{kij}e_m \cdot e_i$$

But this is the point where I hit a bit of trouble. Shouldn't it be possible to replace $e_m \cdot e_i$ for the metric tensor components $g_{mi}$, which would give me:

$$Ric(v, v) = \sum v^j v^k R^m_{kij}g_{mi}$$
$$Ric(v, v) = \sum v^j v^k R_{ikij}$$

At this stage, I'd define:

> $$R_{kj} = R_{ikij}$$

But that seems awkward because usually we'd:

- Contract over an upper and lower index (and)
- The usual definition has $R_{kj} = R^i_{kij}$

So I'd like to figure out where the logic I've applied is wrong here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This upper/lower indice confusion arises when you choose an orthonormal frame, since in this case $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$.

The definition of the Ricci curvature is $ R_{kj} = R^i_{kij}$, where we used the Einstein summation convention. To be precise it's
$$ R_{kj} = \sum_i R^i_{kij}, $$
then by definition
$$ R_{kj} = \sum_i R^i_{kij} = \sum_{i,l} g^{li} R_{lkij}. $$
Using orthonormal frame, we have
$$ \tag{1} R_{kj}= \sum_{i,l} \delta_{il} R_{lkij} = \sum_{i} R_{ikij}. $$

If by $R_{kj} = R_{ikij}$ you mean (1), then there is no mistake, but bad writing style: you used Einstein summation notation even for $R_{ikij}$, which is not invariant under change of (arbitrary) coordinates.

The practice is that we used Einstein notation only for tensor. When you want to calculate using a specific frame, we will be honest and write down all the summations. Sometimes we even use different indices ($\alpha, \beta, \gamma$) to distinguish it from the indices for coordinates basis ($i, j, k$).

Comment: Oh wow, yep that was the exact problem, I just forgot that $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$, doh! Thanks so much :D